# Apple API song "previewUrl" persistence

Tags: ios, itunes

I'm developing an iOS app and I need to allow the user to play the preview of several songs from iTunes into the app.
Now with the lookup API and the `adamID` I can easily find the `previewUrl` and get it to play.

I rad API rules and descriptions and it says that I have to keep an URL to the store to allow the user to buy the song, that I can't save the audio and so on,
however the only thing I want to do is saving the `previewUrl` instead of having to look for it every time, since I'm not very used to use API, and apple use to be much strict sometimes I would love to avoid my app to not be accepted.

So can I "statically" use the `previewUrl` and  the `trackViewUrl` without sending every time  a lookup call and parse the result?

```
{
    "resultCount": 1,
    "results": [
        {
            "someStuff" : "...",
            
            "trackViewUrl": "http://itunes.apple.com/it/album/succede/id480182271?i=480182284&uo=4",
            "previewUrl": "http://a2.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/115/Music/f9/d0/c0/mzm.fvpggyal.aac.p.m4a",
            
            "someMoreStuff" : "...",
            "..." : "..."
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes caching url's is fully supported, there api rules is regarding the actual asset, that is what you can't save and re-play.

It is ideal cache meta-data which reduces redundant requests and improves performance using cached data.